# Using uniqid() for image upload codeignitor

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

So I have two issues as I am learing Codeigniter and PHP frameworks

1. I am using the image upload class from codeigniter, I am trying to make all my image uploads unique, so yes I could use the 'encrypt_name' property in the config, but I want to try something else so I am trying to use the 'uniqid()' function. Still cannot figure it out.
2. I have yet to be able to show fix my upload path on my localhost from codeigniter, It only works if I actually put the full directory path such as C:/admin/folder1/folder2 and so which causes my image link to be broken.

I have tried multiple things as I have shown in my code in comments. I appreciate all the help.

Controller

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->view('upload_file', array('error' => ' ' ));
        }


        public function do_upload()
        {
                $config['upload_path']          = 'C:\wamp64\www\NewUploads';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 0;
                $config['max_width']            = 0;
                $config['max_height']           = 0;
              //  $config['encrypt_name']         = True;
                $config['file_ext_tolower']     = True;
                $config['detect_mime']          = True;





                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                        $this->load->view('upload_file', $error);
                }
                else
                {

                        $data = $this->upload->data();
                      //  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
//$this->show();
                      //$newimage  =  $data['file_name'];
                          $data['full_path'];
                        //  $as = uniqid($newimage, true);




                      //  $new = uniqid($data, True);

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $as);
                }
// doesnt work




        }
}
    ?>
```

View

```
<html>
<head>

  <style>

}
.photo{
display:inline-block;
width: 32%;
border: 5px solid #ddd;
min-height: 300px;
}

</style>


<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

<ul>

<?php


//foreach ($upload_data as $item => $value):?>
<?php //echo $item;?>:


<?php


echo $as;
//echo $file_name . "<br>";
//echo $full_path . "<br>";
echo '<img src="' . $full_path . '" class = "photo">';



?>




<?php// endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<p><?php echo anchor('upload', 'Upload Another File!'); ?></p>

<?php


//echo '<img src="' . $upload_data['full_path'] . '" class = "photo">';


?>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first issue you can encrypt the file name and set overwrite to false, this way if a file with the same name as the one you are uploading exists, it will be overwritten. If set to false, a number will be appended to the filename if another with the same name exists.

```
$config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

Now you guarantee that your file name will always be unique.

And about your second issue you can use relative paths like this:

```
$rel_path = 'NewUploads';
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'NewUploads';
```

And just store the image name in your `db` or with its relative path if it won't change later and upon retrieval add `base_url` to it like this:

```
$upload_path = 'your/upload/path';
$file_url = base_url($upload_path.'/'.$file_from_db);
```

Or in your case if you want to pass it directly to the view as i said you only need the filename like this:

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
$newimage = $data['file_name'];
$upload_path = 'your/upload/path';
$image_url = base_url($upload_path.'/'.$newimage);
```

But just keep in mind to deal with the name only.

---

You can create your own function to create unique file names without changing the core system files of course by merely extending them, but why! when you can already do that with codeigniter by default and with the same results and will always get a unique file name.

Comment: Wow thanks for your help, this makes so much more sense. just to add, where would I use  $image_url = base_url($upload_path.'/'.$newimage); in the view or controller as I dont understand if I use it in the controller how I would be able to pass the variables to the view.

Comment: You have you image name already, you can pass the name to the `view` and use `base_url('upload/path/'.image_name);` there or generate the whole url in the `controller` and pass it to the `view` .. whatever you like.

Comment: You don't know how to pass data to the view? @PHPNoob

Comment: With out using a array I would think it is, $this->load->view('upload_success', $image_url); But that doesnt seem to be correct.... is there a easier way?

Comment: You must enclose your data in array before passing it to the view like this `$this->load->view('your_view', array('image_url' => $image_url);` and in the view you use that array key as your variable, i hope you got it.